# how to prompt user to fill in information when closing windows

Tags: microsoft-word

I want to force a user to fill in information (end time of a meeting) in order to be able to close a word document - in other words, the word document won't close unless end time is entered.
How do I do that?
Thanks!

Comment: Use `Application.DocumentBeforeClose` Event. Check the condition(s) you need and set `Close=False` if any condition does not hold.

Comment: Can you use VBA? BTW, forcing a user to put in data, might not give you the desired result, a better way might be to save the time automatically.

Comment: Beware of a document that once is opened can never be closed unless by killing Word. Asking for confirmation is much better.

Answer (score 0):

The solution requires code, at either the document level, template level, or application level with a COM Add-in/Global Add-in.

The most transportable method would be a document enabled template (docm) that checked as @Akina said, the DocumentBeforeClose event.

Another solution method would be from a Macro Drive Template (dotm) attached to the document. It checks the same event as mentioned above. An inherent problem with this solution method is it requires the template always being attached and that could be a problem in some environments

One more that I can think of is a COM Add-in/Global Add-in that is active in all systems where the document would be used. This potentially is a logistics problem, it limits the documents use to Office versions where the add-ins can be loaded. The document would also have to be marked with a variable that can be checked in the DocumentBeforeClose routine to prevent the routine from stopping the closing of all documents. I believe that is what @harrymc is referring to.